# Local Gitlab cicd failed 'fatal: unable to access...Could not resolve host:...' with linux runner

Tags: docker, dns, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to test my python project and run via gitlab. I have installed runner on my ubuntu notebook and complete registered with local
gitlab server.
Thus, got 2 seperate machine one runner and another one is gitlab server. Both machine can communicate each other.
Notebook(192.168.100.10) ---- GitLab(172.16.10.100)

Once I commit test, my job failed with message below;

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/dz/mytest/.git/
 fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab.lab01.ng/dz/mytest.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab.lab01.ng
Uploading artifacts for failed job
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

From my notebook cli, i can ping gitlab server ip but not the host name even curl also doesnt know the hostname.
I believe this is something to do with the dns that cannot resolved. 
I add hostname in my notebook /etc/hosts , i can ping hostname but still failed run job with the same message.
I have tried people suggest add below inside gitlab-runner config.toml, thus I add below in config.toml (Not sure if this is correct to add in config.toml)

```
[[runners]]
dns_search = [""]
```

Still failed and got the same message could not resilve host.
What can I do on my notebook setting/runner? I dont have admin access to gitlab to check further.
Anyone face the same problem. Appreciate help and support thank you.

--For information I have tried testing the runner on my notebook with public gitlab (gitlab.com) and I can run the job successfully without any error message--

Comment: Have you tested if your ssh keys are working?

Comment: my ssh key work fine...thank you,

Comment: In my case it was the firewall denying requests from docker, use ufw to allow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using docker as the executor for your GitLab runner since you did not specify it in your question. Docker executor does not share the `/etc/hosts` of the host machine but you can use `extra_hosts` parameter inside your `config.toml` to let the runner container know about the custom hostname:

```
[runners.docker]
extra_hosts = ["gitlab.lab01.ng:172.16.10.100"]
```

Comment: Yup its a docker based executor. Thank you for your response and help. Will check it further.